# Getting values separated by comma inside square brackets using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like this:

```
String text = "[Values, one, two, three]";
```

I tried do it with Guava's class Splitter:

```
List<String> split = Splitter.on(",").splitToList(text);
```

But my result is:

```
[Values
one
two
three]
```

How can I get a List with the values one, two and three using Regex?

Comment: How can I get a List with the values one, two and three using Regex? ?? .. Well. by writing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First strip out the `[` and `]` from the string using `replaceAll()`. Then split using `\s*,\s*` which means comma can have optional space before or after it.

```
String []splits = text.replaceAll("^\\s*\\[|\\]\\s*$", "").split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

Now convert the `String` array into `List<String>` using `Arrays.asList()`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this, just use string manipulation.

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(text.substring(1, text.length() - 1).split(", ")));
```

If you need to drop the first value, then just do the following:

```
values.remove(0);
```